# Magento rewrite issue with multi-language store setup and storecodes

Tags: multistore, url-rewrite, magento-1.7.0.1

currently I use a multi-language store setup with Magento 1.7 on a single domain. The URLs looks like this:

```
www.example.com/category/product.html
www.example.com/kategorie/produkt.html
```

For SEO reasons I want to use storecodes:

```
www.example.com/en/category/product.html
www.example.com/de/kategorie/produkt.html
```

Problem: The old structure is fully indexed by google. I don't know how to rewrite those URLs correctly to the right storecode. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please explain how it problem your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your store url to have code **`System > Config > Web > Add Store Code to URLs`**

And make sure you add your desired `store code` Follow these steps:

Go to `System > Manage Store` and edit each store then add your code in `code` section.

**Then add all old url to redirect to new url by editing directly from database.**

The table that is responsible for rewrite is `core_url_rewrite`.

In that table you will be focusing on these columns

1. store_id
2. request_path

Store id is the id for your store. So you want to find out what is the id for `en` and `de`.

Now, export `core_url_rewrite` in **csv** format and make backup of this file then edit `request` path sections and put your all old url in `target path section` as desired.

I am sure you can differentiate your request path by looking at their `store_id`.

After complete edit of that file, upload your `csv` file into that. You should update `url_rewirte_id` as well, since they are set to `auto increment`. Your first `url_rewrite_id` should be greater than last entry on that table and should be in increment basis.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adarsh! Editing the core_url_rewrite table is an interesting idea. But I don't know how changing the request_path can help in this case. The request_path is identical, regardless of whether I use the storecode in the url or not. In my understanding, the storecode is part of the language base url.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think I had misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, I know the store code option. But exactly this leads to the problem, because magento won't redirect automatically. E.g. A product has the URL `www.example.com/category/product.html` for the english version of the product and `www.example.com/kategorie/produkt.html` for the german one. These two URLs are indexed by Google. When I enable the "Add Store Code to URLs" option, the store code will add to the URLs: `www.example.com/en/category/product.html` and `www.example.com/de/kategorie/produkt.html`. The old URLs no longer work now. I won't redirect 500 products manually in the htaccess. :)

Comment: That's exactly where you can add more url redirect in database. I have updated my qst again. Please have a look.

Comment: So basically you are adding new list of redirect, putting all old url in `target` section and new with store code url in `request` section.

Comment: Much thanks again Adarsh! But the `request` path is  `/kategorie/produkt.html` (which is in the google index) not  `/de/kategorie/produkt.html`. I am going to redirect from non-store code URL to store code URL. But there still is a system rewrite from  `/kategorie/produkt.html` to `/catalog/product/view/id/`. When I try to add a redirect in the magento backend from  `/kategorie/produkt.html` to `/de/kategorie/produkt.html`, saving fails with the message "the request path already exists", which make absolutely sense to me.